# Correct way to wrap code that blocks before emitting future in another future

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

I had to wrap a dispatch http request into another Future because it appears that the initial network connection may block (in Netty or whatever is behind it – this is, for example, when computer is only connected to other computer with static IP and no DNS; system blocks for ten seconds or longer before the future is actually created). So instead of

```
  Http(req.OK(JsonUTF))
```

I have now

```
Future {
  blocking(
    Http(req.OK(JsonUTF))
  )
} .flatMap(identity)
```

Is this correct? Is there any disadvantage of `flatMap(identity)` over `flatten`, which is only in Scala 2.12 and uses some "internal executor"?

Or should I use

```
Future {
  val jsonFut = blocking(
    Http(req.OK(JsonUTF))
  )
  Await.result(jsonFut, Duration.Inf)
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away with a single `flatMap` invocation if you do something like this:

`Future.successful(()).flatMap(_ => blocking { Http(req.OK(JsonUTF)) })`

// You can, on Scala 2.12, replace Future.successful(()) with Future.UNIT

Comment: So is `Future.successful(()).flatMap(x)` different from `Future(x).flatMap(identity)`?

Comment: Yes. Future.apply(x) is synthetically equivalent to Future.successful(()).map(_ => x)

Comment: Future(x).flatMap(identity) is as such: Future.successful(()).map(_ => x).flatMap(identity). And what you want is Future.successful(()).flatMap(_ => x)